# How to duplicate Cracked Red Eye Orbs?

Tags: dark-souls

Before I dive into my issue, here's a disclaimer:

**I harshly condone all forms of hacking. I this question is strictly meant to improve my PVP experience and will not affect the combat situation in any way.**

Well, I do not like to seek refuge in hacking, but it has to be done. I own Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition, and I must say the PVP experience is great (apart from the backstab fishing). The only problem is that I do not have any Cracked Red Eye Orbs, and it's too late for me to join the Darkwraith Covenant (in this playthrough at least; already placed the Lordvessel...). So, you see, I have NO consistent methods of acquiring items that would allow me to invade (I do not intend on using Red Sign Soapstone).

I am sure that the duplication of items via Cheat Engine is possible, but I have no idea how to do it. I'd be very thankful if someone would write me a comprehensive yet short tutorial (note that even if I wanted to cheat, a wonderful tool called PVP Watchdog would prevent me from connecting to other players if I had, say 99 Titanite Slabs). My two main questions are:

1. **How to duplicate Red Eye Orbs?**
2. **How to force the game (via Cheat Engine) to make me a Darkwraith +1 AND transmute some item into a Red Eye Orb (which is permanent)?**

Even better, if anyone knows of a "legal" way to get the needed items, let me know (I should mention that I am on NG +4 right now, I've killed all bosses except The Four Kings and Gwyn). Thank you for your answer in advance!

Comment: You can use a save editor to give yourself a red eye orb (there isn't really a benefit to giving yourself cracked eye orbs instead, "duplicating" your items is the same as adding ones you didn't have before). As far as I know, there is no glitch that produces duplicate items, and editing your save to give yourself red eye orbs might cause PVP Watchdog to flag you. My recommendation would be to get the orb on NG+5 or to start a new character entirely to avoid this issue (and you may be over-leveled if you're interested in a lot of PvP, most PvP players will be around SL120).

Comment: The range for invasions with red eye orbs is 0.9X to max level (where X is your SL), so the lowest level player you should be able to invade with one is SL125. You will probably still find players at 139, but the optimal PvP level is considered to be 120 by much of the community. You won't be able to interact with players in the peak range or most players using recommended PvP builds, and you'll probably spend a lot longer waiting to find someone to invade.

Comment: I don't think we can condone cheating in a multiplayer game, no matter how honest the intentions.  Our general stance is if you want to cheat in a single player game, go nuts.  Anything for multiplayer, however benign, is strictly not allowed.

Comment: For the record, as you have mentioned, the *only* way to get a regular source of Cracked Red Eye Orbs is Darkstalker Kaathe, either that, or ask players really nicely before stabbing them in the back.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for a way to cheat in a multiplayer game.

Comment: The pvp system here is arcane and overcomplicated. When the proper answer is 'replay the entire game, you did not do X and Y in the correct order, no invasion multiplayer for you', that's a bit... eh? Especially as Red Eye Orb has no actual effect on the chances of invasion success, and the game communicates this requirement poorly to the player.  Question asker also asks for alternatives if they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's exising Cheat Engine tables for editing pretty much everything you'd want, including changing your current covenant, changing covenant level, giving items, editing stats, etc. As far as I know, Dark Souls: Prepare to Die Edition has no protection or cheat detection whatsoever. As you mentionned, PvP Watchdog can tell if other players have invalid characters so don't do something impossible in the game (however 99 Slabs is possible so no worry about that). It only checks the current player data so you could edit yourself back to, say, lvl 120 and edit your stats appropriately and you'd be in the clear.

You can find such a table at this link. Not mine, I cannot guarantee it will stay available or safe, but at the moment of writing this it works.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_f11g1DlLhDVGcxNG5WdHJfN28

You can use the item replacer script to replace the currently selected item with any item of your choice. For example, replace a wooden arrow with a Red Eye Orb. You could do the same to get a dark hand, and darkwraith armor and sword.

Comment: @GregorPerčič On top of my head: Install Cheat Engine, open the darksouls.ct file with it, in the CE window click the PC icon on the left and in the popup choose the Dark Souls process. In DS, open your inventory and highlight some item you don't mind losing, such as a firebomb. Then, find "Item Replacer" in the list of cheats, check it, then in the popup choose the item you want and press the Replace button. Back in DS, change your selection or close and reopen the menu and the item will have been replaced.

Comment: @GregorPerčič Glad to hear it. Other changes (stats/covenant) should be simple enough but feel free to ping me if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for participating in 1v1 multiplayer duels without the Darkwraith Covenant: Other covenants exist. Why not use one of these for your PvP needs?

[Path of the Dragon](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/path-of-the-dragon) seems like an obvious choice as it does not have any requirements, allows pvp with any player just like the red orb, and you should not be locked out of it.